# Convert bool[] to byte[]

Tags: c#, boolean, arrays

I have a `List<bool>` which I want to convert to a `byte[]`. How do i do this? 
`list.toArray()` creates a `bool[]`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's two approaches, depending on whether you want to pack the bits into bytes, or have as many bytes as original bits:

```
    bool[] bools = { true, false, true, false, false, true, false, true,
                     true };

    // basic - same count
    byte[] arr1 = Array.ConvertAll(bools, b => b ? (byte)1 : (byte)0);

    // pack (in this case, using the first bool as the lsb - if you want
    // the first bool as the msb, reverse things ;-p)
    int bytes = bools.Length / 8;
    if ((bools.Length % 8) != 0) bytes++;
    byte[] arr2 = new byte[bytes];
    int bitIndex = 0, byteIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bools.Length; i++)
    {
        if (bools[i])
        {
            arr2[byteIndex] |= (byte)(((byte)1) << bitIndex);
        }
        bitIndex++;
        if (bitIndex == 8)
        {
            bitIndex = 0;
            byteIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you could calculate bytes in one step by: `int bytes = (bools.Length + 7) / 8;` making second increment line redundant. Also faster (only one division compared to division + modulus)

Comment: great approach - i would remove the basic approach. it's a waste of memory and a `byte` isn't made for storing one `bit`

Comment: @fubo while I agree with you, that's really a question of intent: if that is what is need, then it is what is needed

Answer (score 5):

### Marc's answer is good already, but...

*Assuming* you are the kind of person that is comfortable doing bit-twiddling, or just want to write less code *and* squeeze out some more performance, then this here code is for you good sir / madame:

```
byte[] PackBoolsInByteArray(bool[] bools)
{
    int len = bools.Length;
    int bytes = len >> 3;
    if ((len & 0x07) != 0) ++bytes;
    byte[] arr2 = new byte[bytes];
    for (int i = 0; i < bools.Length; i++)
    {
        if (bools[i])
            arr2[i >> 3] |= (byte)(1 << (i & 0x07));
    }
}
```

It does the exact same thing as Marc's code, it's just more succinct.

Of course if we *really* want to go all out we could unroll it too...
...and while we are at it lets throw in a curve ball on the return type!

```
IEnumerable<byte> PackBoolsInByteEnumerable(bool[] bools)
{
    int len = bools.Length;
    int rem = len & 0x07; // hint: rem = len % 8.

    /*
    byte[] byteArr = rem == 0 // length is a multiple of 8? (no remainder?)
        ? new byte[len >> 3] // -yes-
        : new byte[(len >> 3)+ 1]; // -no-
     */

    const byte BZ = 0,
        B0 = 1 << 0, B1 = 1 << 1, B2 = 1 << 2, B3 = 1 << 3,
        B4 = 1 << 4, B5 = 1 << 5, B6 = 1 << 6, B7 = 1 << 7;

    byte b;
    int i = 0;
    for (int mul = len & ~0x07; i < mul; i += 8) // hint: len = mul + rem.
    {
        b = bools[i] ? B0 : BZ;
        if (bools[i + 1]) b |= B1;
        if (bools[i + 2]) b |= B2;
        if (bools[i + 3]) b |= B3;
        if (bools[i + 4]) b |= B4;
        if (bools[i + 5]) b |= B5;
        if (bools[i + 6]) b |= B6;
        if (bools[i + 7]) b |= B7;

        //byteArr[i >> 3] = b;
        yield return b;
    }

    if (rem != 0) // take care of the remainder...
    {
        b = bools[i] ? B0 : BZ; // (there is at least one more bool.)

        switch (rem) // rem is [1:7] (fall-through switch!)
        {
            case 7:
                if (bools[i + 6]) b |= B6;
                goto case 6;
            case 6:
                if (bools[i + 5]) b |= B5;
                goto case 5;
            case 5:
                if (bools[i + 4]) b |= B4;
                goto case 4;
            case 4:
                if (bools[i + 3]) b |= B3;
                goto case 3;
            case 3:
                if (bools[i + 2]) b |= B2;
                goto case 2;
            case 2:
                if (bools[i + 1]) b |= B1;
                break;
            // case 1 is the statement above the switch!
        }

        //byteArr[i >> 3] = b; // write the last byte to the array.
        yield return b; // yield the last byte.
    }

    //return byteArr;
}
```

**Tip:** As you can see I included the code for returning a `byte[]` as comments. Simply comment out the two yield statements instead if that is what you want/need.

---

**Twiddling Hints:**

Shifting `x >> 3` is a cheaper `x / 8`.

Masking `x & 0x07` is a cheaper `x % 8`.

Masking `x & ~0x07` is a cheaper `x - x % 8`.

---

**Edit:**
Here is some example documentation:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Bit-packs an array of booleans into bytes, one bit per boolean.
    /// </summary><remarks>
    /// Booleans are bit-packed into bytes, in order, from least significant
    /// bit to most significant bit of each byte.<br/>
    /// If the length of the input array isn't a multiple of eight, then one
    /// or more of the most significant bits in the last byte returned will
    /// be unused. Unused bits are zero / unset.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="bools">An array of booleans to pack into bytes.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// An IEnumerable&lt;byte&gt; of bytes each containing (up to) eight
    /// bit-packed booleans.
    /// </returns>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ. This won't be efficient, but will be simple. I'm assuming that you want one byte per bool.

```
bool[] a = new bool[] { true, false, true, true, false, true };
byte[] b = (from x in a select x ? (byte)0x1 : (byte)0x0).ToArray();
```

Comment: I wouldn't bet on this being particularly inefficient, until the input array starts having thousands of entries.

Comment: this won't work. it will return array of bits. (array of bool) and not bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Or the `IEnumerable` approach to [AnorZaken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36572780/5185376):

```
static IEnumerable<byte> PackBools(IEnumerable<bool> bools)
{
    int bitIndex = 0;
    byte currentByte = 0;
    foreach (bool val in bools) {
        if (val)
            currentByte |= (byte)(1 << bitIndex);
        if (++bitIndex == 8) {
            yield return currentByte;
            bitIndex = 0;
            currentByte = 0;
        }
    }
    if (bitIndex != 8) {
        yield return currentByte;
    }
}
```

And the according unpacking where `paddingEnd` means the amount of bits to discard from the last byte to unpack:

```
static IEnumerable<bool> UnpackBools(IEnumerable<byte> bytes, int paddingEnd = 0)
{
    using (var enumerator = bytes.GetEnumerator()) {
        bool last = !enumerator.MoveNext();
        while (!last) {
            byte current = enumerator.Current;
            last = !enumerator.MoveNext();
            for (int i = 0; i < 8 - (last ? paddingEnd : 0); i++) {
                yield return (current & (1 << i)) != 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good code. It does seem to have a bug/typo however, in PackBools() it reads if (bitIndex != 8), but it can never == 8 since the code above already checks for this condition if (++bitIndex == 8) and sets the bitIndex = 0. So it likely should read if (bitIndex != 0) as in the start of the next fresh byte.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any control over the type of list, try to make it a List, which will then produce the byte[] on ToArray(). If you have an ArrayList, you can use:

```
(byte[])list.ToArray(typeof(byte));
```

To get the List, you could create one with your unspecified list iterator as an input to the constructor, and then produce the ToArray()? Or copy each item, casting to a new byte from bool?

Some info on what type of list it is might help.

Comment: False (-1) returns 255 for a signed byte.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class. Depending on the exact nature of your requirement, it may solve your problem quite neatly.

Answer (score 0):

Another LINQ approach, less effective than @hfcs101's but would easily work for other value types as well:

```
var a = new [] { true, false, true, true, false, true };
byte[] b = a.Select(BitConverter.GetBytes).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```