# convert from BitArray to 16-bit unsigned integer in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, int, bit, bitarray

```
BitArray bits=new BitArray(16); // size 16-bit
```

There is bitArray and I want to convert 16-bit from this array  to unsigned integer in c# ,
 I can not use copyto for convert, is there other method for convert from  `16-bit` to  `UInt16`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
UInt16 res = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; i++) {
    if (bits[i]) {
        res |= (UInt16)(1 << i);
    }
}
```

This algorithm checks the 16 least significant bits one by one, and uses the bitwise OR operation to set the corresponding bit of the result.

Comment: res |= (1 << i); can not convert integer(i) to UInt16 (res)  ??

Comment: @user2922938 Oops, I forgot to add a cast. This should work after the edit.

Comment: plz i am beginner in c# can you explain more,what is (cast)?

Comment: @user2922938 I added `(uint16)` in front of `(1 << i)` to tell C# that the expression needs to be converted to `uint16` before using it in an `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through it and compose the value itself.

```
var bits = new BitArray(16);
bits[1] = true;
var value = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
{
    if (lBits[i])
    {
        value |= (1 << i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
    private uint BitArrayToUnSignedInt(BitArray bitArray)
    {
        ushort res = 0;
        for(int i= bitArray.Length-1; i != 0;i--)
        {
            if (bitArray[i])
            {
                res = (ushort)(res + (ushort) Math.Pow(2, bitArray.Length- i -1));
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check this another anwser already in stackoverflow of that question:

[Convert bit array to uint or similar packed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732237/convert-bit-array-to-uint-or-similar-packed-value)

Comment: That example uses COPYTO and he cannot use that as mentioned in the question