# C# byte[] to List<bool>

Tags: c#, byte, boolean, steganography

From bool[] to byte[]: [Convert bool[] to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713057/convert-bool-to-byte-c)

But I need to convert a byte[] to a List where the first item in the list is the LSB.

I tried the code below but when converting to bytes and back to bools again I have two totally different results...:

```
public List<bool> Bits = new List<bool>();


    public ToBools(byte[] values)
    {
        foreach (byte aByte in values)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                Bits.Add(aByte.GetBit(i));
            }
        }
    }



    public static bool GetBit(this byte b, int index)
    {
        if (b == 0)
            return false;

        BitArray ba = b.Byte2BitArray();
        return ba[index];
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using the [BitArray Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) for the whole byte array instead of each single byte?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're only considering 7 bits, not 8. This instruction:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
```

Should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

Anyway, here's how I would implement it:

```
byte[] bytes = ...
List<bool> bools = bytes.SelectMany(GetBitsStartingFromLSB).ToList();

...

static IEnumerable<bool> GetBitsStartingFromLSB(byte b)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        yield return (b % 2 == 0) ? false : true;
        b = (byte)(b >> 1);
    }
}
```