# how to handle extremely large numbers

Tags: c#

I have to be able to handle extreme numbers and large es: consisting of eight million bits, but with which I must be able to perform the operations of division and rest.

This number can also be used as an array of bool

Comment: Did you look at [BigInteger structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Just wanted to add on the array of bools part - in BigInteger you gave `ToByteArray()` that you can use to construct a list of bools (you can see how here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099920/c-sharp-byte-to-listbool ) - but if you need it for byte operations, you have those imlemented in BigInteger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The BigInteger type is an immutable type that represents an arbitrarily large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower bounds.