# How to convert bool [] into byte []

Tags: c#

I have bool array:

```
bool[] b6=new bool[] {true, true, true, true, true, false, true, true,
                      true, false, true, false, true, true, false, false };
```

How can I convert this into an array of bytes such that

- byte[0]=0xFB
- byte[1]=AC
- etc

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713057/convert-bool-to-byte-c-sharp

Comment: What rules govern the conversion? How many bytes do you expect as result?

Comment: What should `true` convert to? And `false`?

Comment: Try the search on top right side, if you don't find any solution, then post the question.

Comment: signed or unsinged byte?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
static byte[] ToByteArray(bool[] input)
{
    if (input.Length % 8 != 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("input");
    }
    byte[] ret = new byte[input.Length / 8];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 8)
    {
        int value = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if (input[i + j])
            {
                value += 1 << (7 - j);
            }
        }
        ret[i / 8] = (byte) value;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

---

EDIT: Original bit of answer before the requirements were clarified:

You haven't said what you want the conversion to do. For example, this would work:

```
byte[] converted = Array.ConvertAll(b6, value => value ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
```

Or similarly (but slightly less efficiently) using LINQ:

```
byte[] converted = b6.Select(value => value ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Didn't know about `Array.ConvertAll`. Thought I had to do a `ToList()` before I could use `ConvertAll`, so +1 for that :)

Comment: I want to result bit 1 to bit 8.but this code  calculate result bit 8 to bit 1.

Comment: @HimanshuBajpai: If you'd given clear requirements to start with, I'd have satisfied them... but it should be pretty easy to change the code above. (Hint: change the line `value += 1 << j;` to shift by a different amount...)

Comment: @HimanshuBajpai: I've now edited the code, mostly for the sake of anyone coming to this question in the future. However, next time you ask a question please give more details *right from the beginning*. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions about asking a question well.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to convert each group of eight booleans into a byte, you can use the `BitArray` class:

```
byte[] data = new byte[2];
new BitArray(b6).CopyTo(data, 0);
```

The array `data` now contains the two values 0xDF and 0x35.

#### Edit:

If you want the result 0xFB and 0xAC, you would have to reverse the booleans in the array first:

```
Array.Reverse(b6, 0, 8);
Array.Reverse(b6, 8, 8);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bytes = (from bit in b6 select bit ? (byte)1 : (byte)0).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Linq:

```
var byteArray = 
b6
.Select(b => (byte)(b ? 1 : 0))
.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] byteArray = Array.ConvertAll(b6, b => b ? (byte)1 : (byte)0);
```

Answered here previously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/713105/181002